# how to stop insertion into database

Tags: c#, asp.net, openoffice-calc

can i stop inserting into database if the cells are empty by checking all the cell values

Comment: Your currently posted code loops through all the columns and checks all of them, not just the mandatory ones.  It should only check the mandatory ones.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting values from a database? You might need to check `IsDBNull(dt.Rows[i][j])`. Also, not sure if this is the source of the problem, but checking if a string is equal to some value, you can use `String.Equals()`. So in your If statement, do

```
if (IsDBNull(dtRows[i][j]) OR dt.Rows[i][j].Equals("")) {
    //code for empty data
}
```

If you're not getting data for DB, it wouldn't hurt to check for Null or Nothing value, not just "" empty string value.